# Resolve hostnames with arch linux on a RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, hostname, archlinux, resolve, dnsmasq

I have a Pi that runs hostapd and dhcpd on arch linux to create it's own land with the Pi's (routers) IP being `10.0.0.1`. This uses the wlan0 interface and it only serves as a standalone router running a web server.

Once I connect to the Pi, I use `10.0.0.1` to display the web pages, but I want to use a hostname such as `firepi`. I have tried using dnsmasq, but I haven't been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated especially if you can give me some detailed examples as I am a novice.

The purpose of this system is that I have created a web app that you can use to ignite fireworks over WiFi at a safe distance. I would just like the convenience of using a hostname instead of the IP address.

I must add that I will more than likely be using an iPhone to connect to the server, should this affect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure how or why but this is what I did and it is successfully working now, so this is just for future users who may need a similar setup to mine.

First I installed hostapd and dhcpd and made sure they were working. Next I changed '/etc/hostname' to firepi and the '/etc/hosts' and added '10.0.0.1 firepi'. Then I installed dnsmasq, and set the interface to wlan0, and finally added '10.0.0.1 firepi' to '/etc/resolv.conf'.

After a full reboot, I joined the network on my iPhone, navigated to firepi and sure enough, it worked!

Thanks to the other users for their advice and tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can use avahi on Arch as well to resolve your hostname:

```
sudo pacman -S avahi nss-mdns
```

Start the avahi daemon:

```
sudo systemctl enable avahi-daemon.service
sudo systemctl start avahi-daemon.service
```

Edit /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
sudo vim /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Change the line:
*hosts: files myhostname dns*
to
*hosts: files myhostname mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns*

Reboot

Note: don't forget to add *.local* to your hostname.

See also:
http://blog.pixxis.be/post/77285636682/resolve-hostname-with-arch-linux-on-a-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to use "firepi" as hostname to connect to it, you can simply add it to your /etc/hosts file using the syntax "IP host".
To make it as easy as possible, run this command as root:

```
echo "10.0.0.1 firepi" >> /etc/hosts
```

That'll do the trick.

Comment: would this still require dnsmasq at all?

Comment: No, totally not. Keep in mind though that it'll work on the local system only, therefore you'd have to add that line to every /etc/hosts file of every device you'll want to reach firepi with. According to your question I think you don't have a problem with that, unless I misunderstood your needs.

Comment: Oh right! Well what I require is to acces it via an iphone or other device which you obviously can't edit a hosts file on. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try avahi ?

`sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon` and

`sudo apt-get install avahi-browse`

I've successfully used that on Raspian. Unless you change the hostname using

`sudo raspi-config` you will access via `raspberrypi.local`

Note that if you plan to access the RPi from Windows you will need to install [Bonjour Service](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999) first(if you have iTunes intalled, you might have those, run `services.msc` and check if the Bonjour Service is started)

Another note: On a friend's iphone I've installed a generic vnc client and had x11vnc running on the RPi and succesfully managed to connect to the RPi (since avahi-daemon was installed)